# Any security issue allowing apostrophe SQL column alias name from Pivot?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, security, sql-injection

Is something like `Select t.value as [silly ' name %'] from Test_Table t` where `[silly ' name%']` came from user input a security threat?

The project I'm working on allows users to re-arrange data via a sql `pivot` making the input values be the columns.  Right now we 'escape' the column names, double quoting any single ticks, which causes the query to fail as it doesn't match the actual text in the table.  Is there any issue with *not* escaping this?

I've been testing simple sql injection as the column name and it doesn't seem to be an issue.

Edit we do wrap brackets in brackets so input like

```
  silly] from Test_Table t; drop table Test_Table;
```

would become

```
  select [silly]] from Test_Table t; drop table Test_Table;]
```

Comment: This is going to depend very much on how you handle your inputs.

Comment: Thats my question though, no sanitizing the input. From what I'm seeing enclosing the text in brackets is safe for any special characters. I guess I'm looking for validation on this, I feel dirty lol.

Comment: If you're substituting ***any*** user input into your SQL, then there is a threat.  In your example what happens if they use `silly] from Test_Table t; drop table Test_Table; --` as their input?  So, ***why*** are you intending to do this?  There must be a safer alternative that you can implement elsewhere in your application.

Comment: If you're using something like prepared statements and your SQL vendor says those characters are fine, you're probably okay. String pasting, not so much.

Comment: @chrylis - There are no prepared statements that allow parameterisation of aliases, column names, etc.  Parameterisation ensures that your parameters are always ***data*** and never ***code***.  This question is ***specifically*** about whether there is a safe way to allow the user to specify an alias for the resulting SQL; that's code, not data.

Comment: @MatBailie forgot to mention we do wrap the brackets in brackets so it would be like `select  [silly]] from Test_Table t; drop table Test_Table;] `  The why is because the application offers a user friendly querying interface with customizable user data inputs. Basically they can create a table of data and use drag and drop sql funcitons on it. One of the functions is `Pivot` which breaks right now if they use a field for the column name that has a `'` in it because we were double quoting it turning it into `''`

Comment: @AdamJames Note, the example I gave ends with `--`, as in "comments".  This means that, if your template is simply `Select t.value as [<user text>] from Test_Table t` then the result becomes `Select t.value as [silly] from Test_Table t; drop table Test_Table; --] from Test_Table t`.  So, wrapping my example in `[` and `]` isn't enough, you also need to do something to the `]` in my "attack" *(such as replacing it or removing it)*.  Still, the principle here is that whatever you come up with, there is a risk that someone cleverer than me ***may*** work out a way to counteract it.

Comment: I strongly recommend you white list allowable characters.  Such as `a-zA-Z0-9 _`, so that you refuse to allow any characters with special meanings *(such as `"`, `'`, `[`, `]`, etc)*.

Comment: Also, to demonstrate that your understanding is imperfect *(like my own, it's not a criticism)* I don't believe that you actually need to double quote the `'` if you are wrapping column names in `[]`...  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5c7bbf53836df94a357c229d1426e58b

Answer (score 0):

Based on: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/constants-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017
and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-quoted-identifier-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 my opinion is that as long as you supply column names in the format of

```
SELECT 1 AS 'Some Name'
```

and remember to **escape single quotes** (double them up) you should be safe.

Examples:

```
SELECT 1 AS 'The level for job_id: %d should be between %d and %d.' 
SELECT 1 AS 'silly] from Test_Table t; drop table Test_Table; --'
SELECT 1 AS ']][["'
SELECT 1 AS '''; SELECT 1 --'
SELECT 1 AS 'SELECT 1 / 0'
```